# How to create multiple App using one project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

How to create multiple executable file/uwp app by using one project?

I have a program which have two version, one is Full Version, one is Lite Version.

But I have only one Project which contain all the code, the only different of full and lite can be adjust in my config, when the config changed, it will turn into lite version with less feature. I need to produce full.exe and lite.exe using only one code based (one project)

```
full.exe
config file will have "full=1".
lite.exe
config file will not contain this info.
```

Same for UWP, How to make two app using only one UWP project?

Comment: In UWP you can work with a trial version system. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/exclude-or-limit-features-in-a-trial-version-of-your-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Compilation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451734/Visual-Studio-Use-Conditional-Compilation-to-Contr) and Preprocessor Directives.
First open Build/Configuration Manager and add new configuration. Call it "Full"
In project properties in Build tab choose this configuration and add to conditional configuration symbols some word. Wor example "Full".
Now you can wrap code that is used in light or in full versions:

```
#If FULL 
   // Insert code to be compiled for full version
#End If
```

update:
If you need trial versions you can use LicenseInformation class and ProductLicenses. Nice article about it:
[Test In-App Purchases in Windows Universal Apps (UWP)](http://kalapos.azurewebsites.net/test-in-app-purchases-in-windows-universal-apps-uwp)

Comment: Does this actually work when deployed to the marketplace? I thought when you're in the market you need to check the license information. (as noted by  Tom in the comments above also)

Comment: It it needed to have purchase possibility, then yes - @Tom-Droste comment is the answer). I have answered how to create multiple app in one project